# Complexity class for probabilistic approximation algorithms with bounded error

Tags: complexity-theory, terminology, complexity-classes, approximation, probabilistic-algorithms

What's the name of a complexity class of 
optimization problems that have 
"bounded error probabilistic approximation algorithms"?
Bounded error probabilistic version of APX 
(as BPP is bounded error probabilistic version of P),
or approximation version of BPP (as APX is approximation version of P).

Comment: This question was reposted and answered on cstheory.se: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/20599/almost-always-almost-right

Comment: The title reminds PAC = "probably approximately correct" which Josh mentioned in his comment on cstheory.